# Execute Javascript function before browser reloads/closes browser/exits page?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to execute a function before a user chooses to reload/close browser/exit page?

I need this for an "online/offline" status function i am trying to write. I want to detect whether the user is still on the page or not.

Any ideas? :)

Maybe there is a better approach to this?

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = function () {...}

Comment: window.onbeforeunload, reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Answer (score 23):

Inline function:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {

    // Cancel the event (if necessary)
    evt.preventDefault();

    // Google Chrome requires returnValue to be set
    evt.returnValue = '';

    return null;
};
```

or via an event listener (recommended):

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(evt) {

    // Cancel the event (if necessary)
    evt.preventDefault();

    // Google Chrome requires returnValue to be set
    evt.returnValue = '';

    return null;
});
```

or if you have jQuery:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function(evt) {

    // Cancel the event (if necessary)
    evt.preventDefault();

    // Google Chrome requires returnValue to be set
    evt.returnValue = '';

    return null;
});
```

Notes:

> When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to
>   confirm the page unload. In most browsers, the return value of the
>   event is displayed in this dialog.
>
> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to
>   window.showModalDialog(), window.alert(), window.confirm() and
>   window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event.

See documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

Use window.onbeforeunload, it is triggered when user leaves your page :http://geekswithblogs.net/hmloo/archive/2012/02/15/use-window.onbeforeunload-event-to-stop-browser-from-closing-or-disable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .unload() called." );
});
```

OR this if you want conformation alert

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {  
   return 'Your dialog message';
};
</script>
```

Comment: TypeError: $(...).unload is not a function