# show javascript message to user using onbeforeunload event only for browser close event

Tags: javascript, html

As per the project requirement, on which I am working now, I need to show user a javascript alert only in the event of browser close using javascript. All other page events like url click, button click, F5 key press etc. are to be disregarded. I have tried with the following code but with no use.

```
var isPostBack = false;

$(function() {
    // You would copy this for select and any other form elements I forgot about

    $('input').live('click', function() { isPostBack = true; });
    $('a').live('click', function() { isPostBack = true; });

    document.onkeydown = function(e) { //attach to key down event to detect the F5 key
        isPostBack = false;

        if (!e) { //Firefox and Safari gets argument directly.
            e = window.event;
        }

        var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

        try {
            if (key == 116) { //F5 Key detected
                isPostBack = true;
            }
        }
        catch (ex) { }
    }
});

window.onbeforeunload = check;

function check() {
    if (!isPostBack) {
        // Do your unload code
        isPostBack = false;

        var strPath = window.location.pathname;

        if (strPath.indexOf('CustomerPortal') >= 0) {
            alert('Customer, you are leaving our page.');
        }
        else {
            alert('User, you are leaving our page.');
        }

        return "Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
    }
}
```

Please help to achieve my target requirement with your valuable comments and help.

Comment: Duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746851/execute-javascript-function-before-browser-reloads-closes-browser-exits-page.  Your issue seems to be this: "Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.showModalDialog(), window.alert(), window.confirm() and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event."

Comment: Are you in control of the javascript that will be used to close the page?

Comment: Thanks all for your quick comments. @Jesse - yes! I am getting the alert message for all the page events. I am unable to seggregate only the browser close event from other page events. Brian - in IE 8 atleast I am getting the alert message. but my problem is that I am unable to seggregate the window close event from other page events as mentioned in my original post.