# clear session on window close when "continue where you left off" setting is turned on in chrome

Tags: php, session

My application logout when browser is closed or by clicking logout button. But when "continue where you left off" is turned on in chrome or firefox the session is not cleared. The browser saves the session value to apply its setting. As my application contains sensitive information i need it to be cleared.I dont want to logout on tab close. Can anyone suggest a way to do this? I already implemented timer logout which does when the tab remains inactive for more than 5 minutes. And it also logout when the browser is closed. "**The problem here is when the "continue where you left off" setting is turned on in browser it does not logout on browser close**". I just want suggestion based on my last point.

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = function(event) { /*perform ajax to clear session here */};` Sorry for posting this as comment, but I am unsure if you are really using javascript or not. If you are not, then its not possible without the help of client side script.

Comment: `session _destroy('')` ..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Javascript function before browser reloads/closes browser/exits page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746851/execute-javascript-function-before-browser-reloads-closes-browser-exits-page)

Comment: also try to avoid saving sensitive data at `$_SESSION`. Use a database

Comment: Dear @Manikiran the question that you have mentioned is not what i am looking for. Its totally different from what i asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want to auto-logout on simple tab-close while other tabs are active, then there is no direct way. Because all client-side scripts have control only within their tabs, they cannot and should not free themselves and gain control over browser window itself.

The other way around would be to instead log-off user, when he haven't had any tab active for, let's say, 30 seconds:

1) Add a script, that is loaded on every page, and it will periodically make an ajax request to the server saying this client is still active.

2) Make an server side script listening to these requests and remembering last time received in current session.

3) And lastly, an script included everywhere after session_start(), that would check said last refresh time and may clear the session if too much time passed since last refresh request (because that would mean client had no tab active for that period of time... or connection problems, cannot be perfect).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion david but i already applied what you have said. Here browser setting messes with logout. Usually when browser is closed it clears session value. Thats why we go for session instead of cache. This setting "continue where you left off" in chrome save session to load pages. I just want to stop it from saving session value or any other suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: The only way how to turn off this setting is using browsers configuration. It is not possible to do it from th script.